# "Plugin For Xamarin Templates" does not exist

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I have downloaded and installed "Cross-Platform .NET Standard Plugin Templates" from below,

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.PluginForXamarinTemplates

but I cannot find "Plugin for Xamarin" template on "New project" window.
Only I can find "Cross-Platform .NET Standard Library Plugin".

On the "Extensions and Updates" window, I searched the word "plugin for xamarin" at Visual Studio Marketplace, but there's no "Plugin For Xamarin Templates".
I tried same way on the movie below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSwH8NrtVCk&feature=youtu.be

How can I use "Plugin for Xamarin" template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it on James Montemagno's (The author of the **Plugin for Xamarin Templates**) [Github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin-Templates), the template is already integrated in **Cross-Platform .NET Standard Plugin Templates**, so you only need to download it.
Download address description：[Plugin for Xamarin Templates](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin-Templates/tree/master/Templates#how-to-get-it)

Comment: Thank you for answering!

I have already tried to download and installed it, but not solved...

On my VS2017, only be added the template "Cross-Platform .NET Standard Library Plugin".
I tried to create new project with it, however, the project has only some C# files, not exist any .csproj or .sln files.

The template degraded...? :_(

Comment: it seems to need to add something yourself,https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin-Templates/tree/master/Templates#plugin-for-xamarin